Transportation management engine. The ResolveAssemblyReference task failed
We are creating TMS engine based on the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/supply-chain/supply-chain-dev/create-new-transportation-management-engine
The solution compiles successfully until we add the reference to one of the following assemblies:
Microfoft.Dynamics.Ax.Framework.Linq.Data
Microfoft.Dynamics.Ax.Framework.Linq.Data.AdoNet
Microfoft.Dynamics.Ax.Framework.Linq.Data.Msil
Microsoft.Dynamics.Ax.Data.Core
Microsoft.Dynamics.Ax.Server.Core
Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Xpp.AxShared
Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.Xpp.Support
assemblies
In that case we get the following
error
Error The **ResolveAssemblyReference** task failed unexpectedly.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.ReferenceTable.GetReference(AssemblyNameExtension assemblyName)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Reference.SetFinalCopyLocalState(AssemblyNameExtension assemblyName, String frameworkPaths, ProcessorArchitecture targetProcessorArchitecture, GetAssemblyRuntimeVersion getRuntimeVersion, Version targetedRuntimeVersion, FileExists fileExists, GetAssemblyPathInGac getAssemblyPathInGac, Boolean copyLocalDependenciesWhenParentReferenceInGac, Boolean doNotCopyLocalIfInGac, ReferenceTable referenceTable)

What could be a cause of the error and how to fix it?
The solution compiles successfully until we add the references

I faced the same issue and I noticed that the problem is ApplicationSuite.dll
You can try setting its "CopyLocal" property value to false then build the solution.
